# .xcf thumbnails on the desktop with xfce

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, thumbnails, thunar

I use Xubuntu 20.04.

To enable thumbnails for my `.xcf` (GIMP) and `.kra` (Krita) files, I followed [this guide](https://moritzmolch.com/blog/1749.html), and with this I get the correct thumbnails in Thunar. However, for a `.xfc`-file on my desktop I do not get any thumbnails (if shown on the desktop, if I open `~/Desktop` in Thunar, I do get thumbnails), whereas this works for `.jpg` files.

Any help would be appreciated :)